# Dart BrowserClient throwing stacktrace when imported

Tags: angular, dart

As soon as I create an instance of BrowserClient, I see a stacktrace in the browser console and the app dies.

```
    import 'package:http/browser_client.dart';
    ...
    var client = new BrowserClient()
        ..withCredentials = true;
```

Stacktrace and relevant code in http/src/utils.dart:

> 'package:http/src/utils.dart': error: line 89 pos 1: unexpected token
>   'Stream' Stream onDone(Stream stream, void onDone()) => ^:
>   package:http/src/utils.dart

```
/// Calls [onDone] once [stream] (a single-subscription [Stream]) is finished.
    /// The return value, also a single-subscription [Stream] should be used in
    /// place of [stream] after calling this method.
    Stream/*<T>*/ onDone/*<T>*/(Stream/*<T>*/ stream, void onDone()) =>
        stream.transform(new StreamTransformer.fromHandlers(handleDone: (sink) {
          sink.close();
          onDone();
        }));
```

If I only import it, the exception looks different - stacktrace and relevant code in async/src/byte_collector.dart

> 'package:async/src/byte_collector.dart': error: line 42 pos 1:
>   unexpected token 'T' T _collectBytes( ^:
>   package:async/src/byte_collector.dart

```
T _collectBytes<T>(
    Stream<List<int>> source,
    T result(StreamSubscription<List<int>> subscription,
        Future<Uint8List> result)) {
```

I'm on the latest version of the browser and http dependencies

```
browser: "^0.10.0+2"
http: "^0.11.3+13"
```

Has anything changed in `BrowserClient` that I need to be aware of? This code used to work fine for the last two years.

I've tried on the Dart versions `1.22.1` and `1.23.0`, I've made sure that Dartium is up to date and matches the Dart version. `pub build` doesn't show any errors either.

Actually, just importing `import 'package:http/browser_client.dart';` alone causes the stacktrace whether it's being used or not.

Full `pubspec.yaml` in case it helps:

```
...
environment:
  sdk: '>=1.13.0 <2.0.0'
dependencies:
  angular2: "^2.2.0"
  bootjack: "0.6.7+2"
  browser: "^0.10.0+2"
  event_bus: "^0.4.1"
  less_dart: any
  http: "^0.11.3+13"
  dart_to_js_script_rewriter: "^1.0.2"
transformers:
- angular2:
    platform_directives:
    - package:angular2/common.dart#COMMON_DIRECTIVES
    platform_pipes:
    - package:angular2/common.dart#COMMON_PIPES
    entry_points: web/main.dart
- dart_to_js_script_rewriter
- $dart2js:
    commandLineOptions: [--enable-experimental-mirrors]
- less_dart:
    entry_points: [web/css/main.less]
    build_mode: dart
```

Downgrading `http` doesn't help either.
I've done a `pub cache repair`, I've deleted the `pubspec.lock` file and re-run `pub get`, the error remains as long as I import / use `BrowserClient`

==================

**Test App to reproduce the problem:**

==================

`lib/components/bug-fix.dart`

```
import 'package:angular2/angular2.dart';
import 'package:angular2/core.dart' show AfterContentInit, Component;
import 'package:angular2/router.dart'
    show ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, Route, RouteConfig;

// uncomment this line to make it crash
// import 'package:http/browser_client.dart';


@Component(
    selector: 'bug-fix',
    template: 'test',
    providers: const [],
    directives: const [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
)
@RouteConfig(const [

])
class AppComponent {



}
```

`web/index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <!--<base href="/">-->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="developed-by" content="jVaaS (Pty) Ltd">
    <title>BugFix APP</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
    <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
    <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css?4">-->
    <!--<script src="cordova.js"></script>-->
</head>
<body >
<bug-fix class="noselect">

</bug-fix>
<script async src="main.dart" type="application/dart"></script>
<script async src="packages/browser/dart.js"></script>

</body>


</html>
```

`web/main.dart`

```
import 'package:angular2/angular2.dart' show provide;
import 'package:angular2/platform/browser.dart';
import 'package:angular2/router.dart' show ROUTER_PROVIDERS;
import 'package:angular2/src/platform/browser/location/hash_location_strategy.dart';
import 'package:angular2/src/platform/browser/location/location_strategy.dart';
import 'package:bugfix/components/bug-fix.dart';

void main() {
    // bootstrap angular2
    bootstrap(AppComponent, [
        ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
        provide(APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/'),
        provide(LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy)
    ]);
}
```

`pubspec.yaml`

```
name: bugfix
version: 2.0.0
description: BugFix
environment:
  sdk: '>=1.13.0 <2.0.0'
dependencies:
  angular2: "^2.2.0"
  bootjack: "0.6.7+2"
  browser: "^0.10.0+2"
  event_bus: "^0.4.1"
  less_dart: any
  http: "^0.11.3+13"
  dart_to_js_script_rewriter: "^1.0.2"
transformers:
- angular2:
    platform_directives:
    - package:angular2/common.dart#COMMON_DIRECTIVES
    platform_pipes:
    - package:angular2/common.dart#COMMON_PIPES
    entry_points: web/main.dart
- dart_to_js_script_rewriter
- $dart2js:
    commandLineOptions: [--enable-experimental-mirrors]
- less_dart:
    entry_points: [web/css/main.less]
    build_mode: dart
```

==================

The above code is literally the only code in the "Bugfix" App. 
I do a `pub get` followed by a `pub serve --port=8888`. As soon as I uncomment the `browser_client` import, it dies with the above stacktraces.

Comment: Was it some update that caused the issue? Perhaps it's because Angular doesn't like generic methods. Hard to tell from the code snippets you posted how stuff is connected.

Comment: It's a brand new project I started on Friday, added in `http` and `browser` yesterday and I just can't get `BrowserClient` to work even though that same code works flawlessly in other Angular projects I've done before.

Comment: I've created a test-app just now with nothing in it, see included code. as soon as I uncomment that `browser_client.dart` import, it dies with a stacktrace in the browser.

Comment: What version did you downgrade to. Have you tried fixing to `0.11.3+9`?

Comment: I've tried fixing the version to each individual version of http that's available on `https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/http` since 2015. None of them worked, each throwing a different exception. My guess is it's not the http library, but something else causing it die.

Comment: Sorry, out of ideas. I just used it yesterday with a new project and I had no issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Created a minimal repo and asked the wife to test it on her machine (https://github.com/janvladimirmostert/angular-dart-browser-client) and it was working fine for her.

Removing all traces of dart and dartium and re-installing dart on my machine fixed it for me.

Very strange :-|